# Need help storing list as table and iterating scraping through pages

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I manage to scrape this e-commerce website and I have for-loop for product name and product price. My first question is how can I combine the two in one table. Second is how can I iterate these in different pages of the website or for multiple urls. Apologies for this stupid question but Im just starting python as I want to use it as a superior scraping tool compared to R where Im more better at. Appreciate any responses.

```
import selenium
driver.get("https://shopee.ph/shop/301669184/search?page=5&sortBy=pop")
productname = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_2wYmLR")
for i in productname:
   x = print(i.text)
productprice = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_1xk7ak")
for l in productprice:
    df2 = print (l.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do the following to put your values in an array.

```
x=[i.text for i in productname]
df2=[l.text for l in productprice]
```

Then you can put them into a dataframe like so

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':x,'price':df2})
print(df)
```

Import

```
import pandas as pd
```

Outputs

```
                                                 name price
0    Crown Kids Boys Round Neck Tshirt in Apple Green    89
1     Crown Kids Boys Round Neck Tshirt in Fern Green    89
2     Crown Kids Girls Round Neck Tshirt in Turquoise    89
3    Crown Kids Girls Round Neck Tshirt in Royal Blue    89
4     Crown Kids Girls Round Neck Tshirt in Navy Blue    89
5    Crown Kids Girls Round Neck Tshirt in Light Gray    89
6   Crown Kids Boys Round Neck Tshirt in Carnation...    89
7      Crown Kids Boys Round Neck Tshirt in Tangerine    89
8          Crown Kids Boys Round Neck Tshirt in Cream    89
9        Crown Kids Boys Round Neck Tshirt in Muroise    89
10  Crown Kids Girls Round Neck Tshirt in Emerald ...    89
11   Crown Kids Girls Round Neck Tshirt in Light Blue    89
12         Crown Kids Boys Round Neck Tshirt in Peach    89
13  Crown Kids Boys Round Neck Dark Color Tshirt C...    89
14  Crown Kids Boys Round Neck Light Color Tshirt ...    89
15        Crown Kids Boys Round Neck Tshirt in Violet    89
```

Comment: You are a godsend. Thank you so much! Marked as answer

Comment: Maybe just a followup. Is there any way to reiterate this code to multiple pages of the url? e.g. search?page=1, search?page=2 etc.